# Creating a nested unordered list from a unique ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this is a shot in the dark, but here it goes. I've been trying to build an unordered list using ruby similar to the one below, but here is the catch: the data that I am receiving from an API is not in a easily parsable format.

I know that I'm going to have to use recursion, but I'm not sure how I can convert it properly into a nested (parent - children) ruby hash.

Any suggestions or references to resources to solve my issue will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time for reading this question.

#### Ruby Array

```
[ [ "Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12.mp4", 3450211337 ],
  [ " Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\video VC-1 BD TEST SAMPLE\\video VC-1 BD SAMPLE.mkv", 249150757 ],
  [ " Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\subs idx\\English.idx", 62582 ],
  [ " Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\subs idx\\French.idx", 43725 ],
]
```

#### Desired Unordered List

```
<ul>
  <li>Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12
    <ul>
      <li>Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12.mp4 - (3450211337)</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>video VC-1 BD TEST SAMPLE</li>
      <ul>
        <li>video VC-1 BD SAMPLE.mkv - (249150757)</li>
      </ul>  
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>subs idx
        <ul>
         <li>English.idx - (62582)</li>
         <li>French.idx - (43725)</li>
        </ul>  
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Just wanted to say thank you all for the guidance and help. I used the assistance to launch a tree view of the torrent files on my site: [moviemagnet.net](https://moviemagnet.net/movies/1-lost-in-translation)

[image: tree view of torrent files]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following block will produce a hash that follows the above layout. It is not recursive, it goes to depth "1" only. I hope this is enough.

```
array = [ [ "Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12.mp4", 3450211337 ],
  [ " Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\video VC-1 BD TEST SAMPLE\\video VC-1 BD SAMPLE.mkv", 249150757 ],
  [ " Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\subs idx\\English.idx", 62582 ],
  [ " Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\subs idx\\French.idx", 43725 ]]
hash={}

array.each do |i|
  j=i.join(', ').split('\\').map(&:strip) # split at '//'
  k=j[0] 
  j.shift
  if hash[k].blank?
    hash[k]=j
  else
    l = hash[k].map{|v| v[0]} # check the first element of each item in the array
    p = l.index j[0]
    if p.nil? # see if current item already there
      hash[k] << j
    else
      j.shift
      hash[k][p][1] = Array(hash[k][p][1]) # if it's string, make it array
      hash[k][p][1] << j.join(" ")
    end
  end
end

# hash
{"Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12"=>
    [
        "Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12.mp4, 3450211337", 
        ["video VC-1 BD TEST SAMPLE", "video VC-1 BD SAMPLE.mkv, 249150757"], 
        ["subs idx", ["English.idx, 62582", "French.idx, 43725"]]
    ]
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to answer my question. I've spent a few hours trying to wrap my head around the second if else conditional using the index method, and it is finally makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my shorthand writing, I was low on time yet I couldn't resist a good problem. Please, feel free to ask if there is anything you wish for me to clear out.

Comment: Instead of `k=j[0]; j.delete j[0]` you should just do `k = j.shift`. (In addition to just being simpler, `delete` will delete all matching elements from the array, which could cause undesired behavior.)

Comment: Also `hash[k].map{|v| v[0]}` should just be `hash.keys`.

Comment: Ok for first comment, I'll replace from pc. But `v` is an array

Answer (score 2):

The recursive method below should work for any number of levels. This code produces a hash, which you can use to easily format the text as desired.

**Code**

```
def doit(a)
   return a.first if a.size == 1
   sz = common_prefix_size(a)
   {a.first.first[0, sz]=>
     a.map { |b| [b.first[sz..-1], b.last] }
      .group_by { |b| b.first[0] }
      .values
      .map { |b| doit(b) } }
end

def common_prefix_size(a)
  i = 0
  loop do
    return i if (a.map { |b| b.first[i] }.uniq.size > 1) || a.first.first == nil
    i += 1
  end
end
```

**Example**

I've eliminated the leading space in all but the first element of "Ruby Array" (assuming they were typos).

```
a = [ [ "Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12.mp4", 3450211337 ],
      [ "Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\video VC-1 BD TEST SAMPLE\\video VC-1 BD SAMPLE.mkv", 249150757 ],
      [ "Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\subs idx\\English.idx", 62582 ],
      [ "Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\subs idx\\French.idx", 43725 ],
    ]

doit(a)
  #=> {"Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\"=>
  #     [ ["Lost in Translation...tomcat12.mp4", 3450211337],
  #       ["video VC-1...SAMPLE.mkv", 249150757], 
  #       {"subs idx\\"=>
  #         [ ["English.idx", 62582],
  #           ["French.idx", 43725]
  #         ]
  #       }
  #     ]
  #   }
```

**Explanation**

Consider first the helper method `common_prefix_size(a)`. This takes an array of two-element arrays as an argument. The first element of each two-element array is a string. This method returns the largest integer `n` such that the first `n` characters of all the strings are equal. `n` can be between `0` and the size of the shortest string. Note that if `s.size => n` for a string `s`, `s[m] => nil` for `m >= n`.

For `a` above:

```
common_prefix_size(a) #=> 55
```

meaning the common string is:

```
a.first.first[0,55]
  #=> "Lost in Translation 2003 BDRip 1080p AAC x264-tomcat12\\"
```

`doit` returns `a.first` if `a.size == 1`, where `a`, its argument, is a subarray of the initial `a`, except the first so-many characters of each string have been removed, as explained below.

If `a.size > 1`, `doit` obtains `sz = common_prefix_size` to determine the sole key for the hash it will return, that key being:

```
a.first.first[0, sz]
```

It then maps `a` into an array for which the first element of each element is a string obtained by removing the first `sz` characters. The elements of the array obtained are then grouped on the first character of the first element of each (a string). (Making the elements of `a` to be two-element arrays certainly complicates this explanation. :-) ). This grouping is a hash, whose keys are the distinct first letters referred to above. Each value of this hash, a subarray of `a` after lopping off the beginning of the strings) is then passed to `doit`. Whew!

I appreciate that this explanation may require a second reading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. After the initial read through, I knew this answer had to come from a professor. This is going to take a few hours to completely comprehend (which isn't a bad thing).

Comment: Yes, I was once a professor, but that was 40 years ago!